# Use PATH variables from windows on windows subsystem linux 2

Tags: linux, windows, environment-variables, path

As you can see in the title I want to use the variables in the PATH of my Windows 10 inside Windows Subsystem Linux 2, I've installed node, composer, and Xammp in Windows 10, but when I try to run any command of PHP, composer or node I got an error something like this "Command 'php' not found, but can be installed with:". I know that I can install in WSL 2 but I don't want to reinstall all my environment in WSL 2, there is a way to export my PATH variables??

[image]

Comment: [Share Environment Vars between WSL and Windows | Windows Command Line](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/commandline/share-environment-vars-between-wsl-and-windows/)

Comment: still unresolved, ah